# Unable to install Photoshop CC on Ubuntu 12

Tags: windows, wine, playonlinux, photoshop

Every time I'm trying to install Photoshop using wine by following [these](http://geebzor.com/tech/linux/complete-guide-to-running-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-13-10/) steps the installation has problems with copying files. I get following errors in wine:

```
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {88d969c0-f192-11d4-a65f-0040963251e5} could be created for context 0x17
err:ole:COMPOBJ_DllList_Add couldn't load in-process dll L"C:\\windows\\system32\\msxml6.dll"
err:ole:create_server class {88d96a05-f192-11d4-a65f-0040963251e5} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {88d96a05-f192-11d4-a65f-0040963251e5} could be created for context 0x17
err:ole:apartment_getclassobject DllGetClassObject returned error 0x80040111
err:ole:create_server class {88d969c0-f192-11d4-a65f-0040963251e5} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {88d969c0-f192-11d4-a65f-0040963251e5} could be created for context 0x17
fixme:file:MoveFileWithProgressW MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH unimplemented
fixme:file:MoveFileWithProgressW MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH unimplemented
fixme:file:MoveFileWithProgressW MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH unimplemented
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x399c80) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x10006510) stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"Adobe Setup"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x40020001,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x339430,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x8485b4) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x102ae028) stub
```

Ubuntu version is 12.04, Photoshop - CC, wine - 1.7.18. Tried on 32 and 64bit. PlayOnLinux doesn't help either.

I can copy missing dlls from existing windows 8 drive if there is a need.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop CC is now working by installing following libraries in POL:

- `POL_Call POL_Install_atmlib`
- `POL_Call POL_Install_corefonts`
- `POL_Call POL_Install_FontsSmoothRGB`
- `POL_Call POL_Install_gdiplus`
- `POL_Call POL_Install_msxml3`
- `POL_Call POL_Install_msxml6`
- `POL_Call POL_Install_tahoma2`
- `POL_Call POL_Install_vcrun2008`
- `POL_Call POL_Install_vcrun2010`